# After importing ActionbarSherlock, the original project has a red exclamation mark

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I downloaded the ActionbarSherlock library, and tried to use it as a library in a different project. As soon as I imported the ActionbarSherlock library, my original project got a red exclamation mark next to it and I got the error that I have dependency errors (actionbarsherlock/bin missing).

This is the error:

```
[2013-06-03 15:27:05 - Live Marketing Help] Path: C:\Users\Alex\workspace\actionbarsherlock\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-06-03 15:27:05 - Live Marketing Help]     Length: 271754
[2013-06-03 15:27:05 - Live Marketing Help]     SHA-1: 53307dc2bd2b69fd5533458ee11885f55807de4b
[2013-06-03 15:27:05 - Live Marketing Help] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

Would anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is the  `Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies` message. In this case, it means it found 2 different versions (check is based on SHA-1) of `android-support-v4.jar` in the dependency list: the one in your project and the other in the `\libs' folder in ActionbarSherlock.

You have two possible solutions:

- The simplest is to keep ActionbarSherlock's support library and delete the one in your project.
- The "stupid" solution is to have exactly the same JAR file in both projects.

Comment: thanks, but take a look at the comments to the other answers. I still got a weird error right after.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I just deleted `android-support-v4.jar` from my main project and rely on the one that is located inside `actionbarsherlock\libs`.

Comment: I tried it and it seemed to make some errors go away, but when I ran the project, I got this error right away: Could not find project_name.apk!

Comment: Close Eclipse and restart it (I wont admit having said this ;o))

Comment: There are lots of similar issues with Eclipse. If it doesn't work, try  checking if your isLibrary checkbox remains inchecked as it should (GProjec->Properties->Android->Uncheck the "Is Library" checkbox)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31152/discussion-between-genadinik-and-alejandro-colorado)

Answer (score 1):

You have to delete the android-support-v4.jar in your project since the **actionbarsherlock** has already its own **android-support-v4.jar**. It will make the support **redundant**, and that's why it has red *exclamation*.

Comment: thanks, I did that, and it seemed to make some errors go away, but when I ran the project, I got this error right away: Could not find project_name.apk!